# Splitted Power supply oscillating

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, analog, noise, oscillator

I am trying to build a circuit featuring multi-channel digitally-control current source and voltage meter.

Each current source is required to supply up to 5mA of current to a load that could reach a voltage as high as 10V. I chose a NXP constant current source device which can supply maximum 50mA of current and support a max voltage of 50V. The current source can be adjusted using an external resistor. I use a digital potentiometer to act as this external resistor so that I can control the current source digitally. The current source circuit is illustrated as followed.
[image: Current Source Circuit]

I have to generate both the 3.3V and -15V power supplies because the Digital Potentiometer requires that the voltage applied to both terminals should not exceed the [0V,3.3V] range in either direction, while my current source load requires a voltage range of 0-10V.

To generate both 3.3V and -15V, I use a power op-amp like TI's LM675 to split a 24V power supply into [0V,+9V] and [-15V,0V] dual ranges. Then I use the +9V to generate two 3.3V supplies for analog and digital circuit respectively. U108 and U109 in the figure below are voltage regulators and generate fixed 3.3V output.
[image: Power op-amp]

In the last part of my circuit, I use a 24bit ADC to measure the voltage of a signal, which is buffered using an Op-amp that directly connect its output to the negative input (voltage follower). In the figure below, U1 and U3 are two-channel 24-bit ADCs and U2 is a four channel op-amp. The DVDD is only used to communicate with the ADC chip and configure the digital potentiometer.
[image: ADC and op-amp]

In total, I have 20 channels of those current source and volt meter all sharing the same AVDD, DVDD, AGND and VGND.

Problem: the output of the power op-amp (U114) is extremely unstable. The power supply path is oscillating.

I have tried to remove both the 3.3V voltage regulator, but the same problem remains and now DGND=2.5V while DVDD=2.1V (with reference to the 24V power ground). Can anyone provide a hint?

Comment: You probably have too much capacitance on the output of the op-amp.  How much total capacitance is connected to the output of the amplifier and small signal AC ground?

Comment: I can't figure out how your U114 rail splitter is supposed to give you +9v/-15v ... Even if it didn't oscillate it would still split your supply evenly into +12v/-12v. And where does the DGND net come from? Your U114's output is driving VGND.

Comment: Have you tried complementary darlingtons on U114 output with feedback from that?

Comment: @JohnD I am worrying about the output capacitance too. I didn't not have an accurate number. The VGND is connected to 18 IC chips, each draws about 1 or 2 mA. The AGND is also connected to 15 IC chips, each draws about 1mA.

Comment: @brhans Sorry I label it wrong, there is no DGND, only VGND and AGND. The output of U114 is set by R59, R60 and R61, which gives about 12*(1+5.5/(2+20)) = 15V.

Comment: @TonyStewart Sorry I don't quite get your point. Do you suggest to use an extra Darlington Transistor as a buffer to the output of U114?  Or use it in the feedback path? What is the benefit?

Comment: No it doesn't. Run a simulation. It splits your supply in half.

Comment: @brhans Acutally, you are right! it is 12V, because I shouldn't connect R58 and R59. This configuration is copied from the spec of LM675. So I didn't spend time to examine it. I will try to disconnect the two resistor and try again. However, even it is 12V, the entire circuit should still work though. Let's see what will happen

Comment: Your schematics are hard to read... but the lm675 has a rail spliiter circuit.  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm675.pdf  Yours looks different, and doesn't have the 1 ohm / 0.22uF cap on the output... maybe try adding that.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold C66 is my 0.22uF cap, although I don't add the 1 ohm.

Answer (score 1):

@brhans Thank you for your valuable hint. I separate the input paths of the LM675. When there is no load at the output, U114 acts exactly as expected, giving me a 15V. However, whenever I connect the output with the load, it starts to oscillate.

Then I notice that both input signals are oscillating too. So I tried adding a 1uF cap to each of the input signal and BINGO! the output becomes really stable. So the schematic looks like this now. 
[image: Voltage split with stable output]

I don't have enough knowledge to explain this. The noise may come from the -15V connection to all the current source ICs. But they are all turned off at time of testing.

Comment: C66 causes less phase margin with DC load current (lag), while C15 causes more phase margin with Phase leading derivative.  and C14 decouples supply noise.  I was suggesting output buffers to reduce the DC load current, but if this works ...ok. when phase margin gets near 0 it oscillates.